# MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN was detected in ViewGroup's onInterceptTouchEvent method in Android?

Tags: android, events, motion

I extended the `ViewGroup` to create a custom view.

In the touch events, when my second finger touched the screen, `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` was not detected in the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Does `onInterceptTouchEvent` method allow multi-touch?

My real device is a 2.2 handset. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {

              final int action = event.getAction();
              float xPosition = 0;
              float yPosition = 0;

                  switch (action){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                                xPosition = event.getX();
                                yPosition = event.getY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN :
                                xPosition = event.getX(1);
                                yPosition = event.getY(1);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try capturing MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN instead?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with what they are asking.